# How to toggle only the class for the element whose button is clicked with jQuery. Currently it toggles all elements with same class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to open and close elements by toggling a class on the click event. I am using jQuery. But on clicking, all elements get opened (which have the same class), however, I only want the one which is clicked to be opened. Here's the link to the [demo page](http://www.lindsaysteele.com/demo-page-1)

```js
$(function() {
  $(".image-button-wrapper").addClass("photo-btn");
  $(".design-layout-card").addClass("menu-plugin");
  $(".design-layout-card").addClass("unactive");
  $(".image-button-wrapper").click(function() {
    $(".design-layout-card").toggleClass("unactive", 1000);
  })
});
```

```html
<div class="sqs-block image-block sqs-block-image sqs-text-ready" data-block-type="5" id="block-yui_3_17_2_1_1660582617675_7984">
  <div class="sqs-block-content" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1660757592153_72">
    <figure class="sqs-block-image-figure image-block-outer-wrapper image-block-v2 design-layout-card combination-animation-none individual-animation-none individual-text-animation-none image-position-left image-linked sqs-narrow-width sqs-text-ready menu-plugin unactive"
      data-scrolled="" data-test="image-block-v2-outer-wrapper" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1660757592153_71">
      <div class="intrinsic" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1660757592153_70">
        <div class="image-inset" data-animation-role="image" data-description="" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1660757592153_69">
          <div class="sqs-image-shape-container-element content-fit" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1660757592153_68">
            <noscript><img class="sqs-image-min-height" src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/52437378e4b02cd2cb2b1250/991c3f4c-e82c-45b0-9216-bc4429b1e9bb/Dumplings.jpg" alt="" loading="lazy" /></noscript>
            <img class="sqs-image-min-height loaded" data-src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/52437378e4b02cd2cb2b1250/991c3f4c-e82c-45b0-9216-bc4429b1e9bb/Dumplings.jpg" data-image="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/52437378e4b02cd2cb2b1250/991c3f4c-e82c-45b0-9216-bc4429b1e9bb/Dumplings.jpg"
              data-image-dimensions="900x900" data-image-focal-point="0.5,0.5" alt="" loading="lazy" data-parent-ratio="333.0" style="left: 166px; top: 0px; width: 1px; height: 1px; position: absolute;" data-image-resolution="500w" src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/52437378e4b02cd2cb2b1250/991c3f4c-e82c-45b0-9216-bc4429b1e9bb/Dumplings.jpg?format=500w"
            />
            <div class="image-overlay" style="overflow: hidden;"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <figcaption class="image-card-wrapper" data-width-ratio="">
        <div class="image-card sqs-dynamic-text-container">
          <div class="image-title-wrapper">
            <div class="image-title sqs-dynamic-text" data-width-percentage="23.3" style="font-size: max(0.75rem, 23.3%);">
              <p class="" style="white-space: pre-wrap;"><strong>Johnny Walker Black Dumplings</strong></p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="image-subtitle-wrapper">
            <div class="image-subtitle sqs-dynamic-text" data-width-percentage="23.3" style="font-size: max(0.75rem, 23.3%);">
              <p class="min-font-set" style="white-space: pre-wrap;">Local ground pork, Johnnie Walker Black Whiskey, green onion, sesame oil, sriracha aioli, sweet soy handmade by @TheRealDumplingKing.</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="image-button-wrapper photo-btn">
            <span class="item-photo-btn"><i class="br-ico"></i></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the parent/child relationship between `.design-layout-card` and `.image-button-wrapper`. Please post example HTML.

Comment: You need to use jQuery's DOM traversal methods to navigate from `.image-button-wrapper` to `.design-layout-card`, using the `this` reference within the click handler function. Exactly how you do that will depend on the HTML, which you unfortunately haven't shown us.

Comment: @WillD I have posted the HTML

Comment: Your HTML does not include any element with `.design-layout-card` class. This is the key. We need to know where it lies in relation to the button. If it is completely unrelated. Then you need to provide some sort of unique identifier to your button to tell it which `.design-layout-card` to control. Something like  `<div class="image-button-wrapper photo-btn" data-controls="1">`   then in your JS you would use that data attribute to select which element to toggle.

Comment: @WillD For some reason whole HTML didn't show up. Can you please give it a check now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

Just create a class for the selected item and remove it from everyone just before adding it again on the clicked item.

```js
$(".list-item").on("click", function(){
  $(".list-item").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
ul li{
  padding: 6px 15px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 5px 0px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: fit-content;
}

li.active{
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="list-item active">Option 1</li>
  <li class="list-item">Option 2</li>
  <li class="list-item">Option 3</li>
  <li class="list-item">Option 4</li>
  <li class="list-item">Option 5</li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: .design-layout-card is the parent of .image-button-wrapper which is being used to toggle class for .design-layout-card